# How to click a button through coding?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two buttons in my program and i want that when i press first button the second button is clicked automatically ( in the event handler of first button , i want to press the second button through coding).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        passWord = pwd.Text;
        user = uName.Text;


        loginbackend obj = new loginbackend();
        bool isValid = obj.IsValidateCredentials(user, passWord, domain);
        if (isValid)
        {
            loginbackend login = new loginbackend();
            passWord = pwd.Text;

            login.SaveUserPass(passWord);
            HtmlDocument webDoc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
            HtmlElement username = webDoc.GetElementById("__login_name");
            HtmlElement password = webDoc.GetElementById("__login_password");

            username.SetAttribute("value", user);
            password.SetAttribute("value", passWord);

            HtmlElementCollection inputTags = webDoc.GetElementsByTagName("input");

            foreach (HtmlElement hElement in inputTags)
            {
                string typeTag = hElement.GetAttribute("type");
                string typeAttri = hElement.GetAttribute("value");

                if (typeTag.Equals("submit") && typeAttri.Equals("Login"))
                {
                    hElement.InvokeMember("click");

                    break;
                }
            }
            button3_Click(sender, e);
            label1.Visible = false ;
            label3.Visible = false;
            uName.Visible = false;
            pwd.Visible = false;
            button1.Visible = false;
            button2.Visible = true;
    }
         else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
        }

    }
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument webDoc1 = this.webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElementCollection aTags = webDoc1.GetElementsByTagName("a");

        foreach (HtmlElement link in aTags)
        {
            if (link.InnerText.Equals("Show Assigned"))
            {
                link.InvokeMember("click");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raise button (or any control) click event manually. C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817343/raise-button-or-any-control-click-event-manually-c). Also read the second highest voted answer, which is the way I would go (i.e. not simulating the click, but rather move the functionality to a separate method).

Comment: on click of first button credential are filled , a login button is pressed and secondly i want that in the new page of website there is a link , which i want to press. for pressing it i found out only one way that is putting the code in a second button and calling it in the first button , but this is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're describing is that you want to call a method when button B is clicked, but then also call that method when button A is clicked.

```
protected void ButtonA_Click(...)
{
    DoWork();
}

protected void ButtonB_Click(...)
{
    // do some extra work here
    DoWork();
}

private void DoWork()
{
    // do the common work here
}
```

Depending on your implementation in the event handlers, you can also just call the event handler of the second button from that of the first, but the above way is the 'right' way to do it.

Comment: Actually the first button is handling two events, firstly its sending credentials to a first website pressing a login button in it and secondly in the first page of website there is a link which i want to click and to achieve that i have associated it with a button , which is pressed through coding in the event handler of first button , but both things are not happening together

Comment: Can you post some code? It sounds like you've got something missing somewhere.

Comment: @James: So create two methods.  Button1 can call both methods.  Button3 will call only the bit that is specific to Button3.  Separate your logic from your UI, you'll thank yourself later.

Answer (score 2):

You could just call the method.

```
    private void btnA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        doA();
    }
    private void doA()
    {
        //A stuff
    }

    private void btnB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        doA();
        doB();
    }
    private void doB()
    {
        //B stuff
    }
```

Or call the _Click method directly;

```
    private void btnB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnA_Click(sender, e);
        doB();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you don't really care whether the button is clicked or not, you just care that the code of the second button is executed. So... just call it:

```
void button1_Click(...)
{
    button2_Click(...);
}
```

Comment: @DH invoking the button2_Click from the the button1_Click handler risks passing the incorrect "sender" reference. Invoking button2.PerformClick() preserves that button 2 is the sender. (Yes you could call button2_Click(button3, e); but I would argue that .PerfomClick() is more reliable because you don't have to keep track of the sender.)