# How to click a button by using keys

Tags: c#, button, user-controls, shortcut

I've a question that How can I click a button that enters text in a text box by using keyboard keys ...
I've worked on this code but it only works when the button is highlighted,

```
private void button1_KeyDown (object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Numpad1)
      {
      button1.performClick();
      textbox.text += button1.text;
      input += button1.text;
      }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539854/how-to-click-a-button-through-coding

Comment: i am making a calculator and i want that when I press numpad keys it presses respective button in the calculator

Comment: Try to hook on the forms ProcessCmdKey event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write KeyDown event on your form.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Numpad1)
    {
        button1.performClick();
        textbox.text += button1.text;
        input += button1.text;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Numpad2)
    {
        button2.performClick();
        textbox.text += button2.text;
        input += button2.text;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    //rest of the code to handle other numpad keys
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate the `KeyDown` listener not to the button itself but to the `Window` element